If bromomethyl cyclopentane reacts with Alcoholic KOH with Heat. Can this produce some very minor products through E1 mechanism also?
I know that alcoholic KOH with heat will majorly give E2 mechanism products but I want to know if it is possible to get minor products through E1 mechanism here also.
The carbocation generated here may get rearranged also which may increase the stability of the carbocation. So, just curious to know if there is any extremely small possibility here for the E1 mechanism also.
If possible any good reference for this.

There is competition among the various possible mechanisms; that is why one tries to run reactions at the conditions to maximize the product wanted. This usually does not eliminate parallel reactions but can make them insignificant. This is discussed in most organic texts.
